# Rotate element according to another element (sticky)

Tags: css, svg.js

I am trying to rotate text block that should be sticky to bottom of red rectangle always (like in Figma, but more simplier). Example if I turned rectangle by 180 degrees, text should be on the top, and it shouldn't enter the rect visual part or highly deviate from it. How can I reach that?

Maybe it's about transform-origin, but I have already broken up my head trying to dynamic set it.

There is the minimal fiddle contains rect and text elements created by svg.js (svg.js is not the part of deal, so you could do it with pure css):

https://jsfiddle.net/8h4q0fLc/1/

Here is the code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/svgdotjs/svg.select.js/3.0.1/dist/svg.select.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="editor"></div>

    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/2.7.1/dist/svg.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/svgdotjs/svg.select.js/3.0.1/dist/svg.select.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/svgdotjs/svg.resize.js/1.4.3/dist/svg.resize.min.js" defer></script>
    <script>
    const editor = SVG('editor').size('100vw', '100vh');
    
    const rect = editor.rect(100, 100).fill('red').move(50, 50).selectize().resize();
    const {x: rectX, y: rectY, width: rectWidth, height: rectHeight} = rect.bbox();
    
    const text = editor.text(`${rectWidth} x ${rectHeight}`).resize();
    const { width: textWidth } = text.rbox();
    text.move(rectX + (rectWidth - textWidth)/2, rectY + rectHeight);
    
    rect.on('resizing', function() {
        text.rotate(this.transform('rotation'));
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem, needs to be contained directly in your question - in text form, and properly formatted. Do not just dump it onto an external platform.

Comment: If you inspect what actually happens via your browser dev tools, then you’ll see that this does not just apply `transform: rotate(…)` to the text, but in fact a complex transformation _matrix_. And even just adding `transform-origin: center` makes it go absolutely haywire already. So unless you want to delve into what complex voodoo math is going on there to calculate that transformation matrix, I doubt there is a simple solution.

Comment: Maybe you could put the text into an element that has the same center point as the box to begin with? Assuming that they both get rotated in the same way, that could perhaps achieve the desired effect without much extra calculation work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to the comments: This is not voodoo but a simple rotation matrix with added translation to counter act the default origin of svg (which is the top left of the svg canvas btw)

If you want to rotate text and rectangle together, the easiest thing you can do is putting it into the same group and rotate the whole group instead. The other approach is, to rotate the text around the center of the rectangle. Therefore you have to pass a second and third parameter to rotate.

```js
const {x: rectX, y: rectY, width: rectWidth, height: rectHeight, cx, cy} = rect.bbox();

rect.on('resizing', function() {
  text.rotate(rect.transform('rotation'), cx, cy);
});
```

Working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/Fuzzy/d28cbvjz/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Thanks!